# Parsing selected code with AST

Tags: java, eclipse

I have selected a piece of code and I want to parse with AST with the purpose of identify methods in the selected code.

```
public void run(IAction action) {
    SelectedText selectedText;      
    IEditorPart editor = getActiveEditor();

    if (editor instanceof AbstractTextEditor) {
        selectedText = getSelectedText(editor);
        creteAST(selectedText);
    }           
}

private void creteAST(SelectedText selectedText) {
    CompilationUnit parse = parse(selectedText);
    MethodVisitor visitor = new MethodVisitor();
    parse.accept(visitor);

    System.out.println("Printing methods from the selected code");
    for (MethodDeclaration method : visitor.getMethods()) {
        System.out.println("Method name: " + method.getName()+ ". Return type: " + method.getReturnType2());
        System.out.println(method);
    }
}

private static CompilationUnit parse(SelectedText selectedText) {
    String s_text = selectedText.getSelectedText();
    char[] c_text = s_text.toCharArray();
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    parser.setSource(c_text);
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    return (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
  }
```

As you can see, I have to change the type from `SelectedText` to `char[]` before parsing.

I am doing something wrong because the parser does not find any method.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javadoc for ASTParser.setResolveBindings() says:

> Binding information is obtained from the Java model. This means that
>   the compilation unit must be located relative to the Java model. This
>   happens automatically when the source code comes from either
>   setSource(ICompilationUnit) or setSource(IClassFile). When source is
>   supplied by setSource(char[]), the location must be extablished
>   explicitly by calling setProject(IJavaProject) and
>   setUnitName(String). Note that the compiler options that affect doc
>   comment checking may also affect whether any bindings are resolved for
>   nodes within doc comments.

```
IJavaProject javaProject = ...obtain it somehow, possibly through getAdapter() on editor?
String name = ...from editor?...

ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
parser.setSource(c_text);
parser.setResolveBindings(true);
parser.setProject(javaProject);
parser.setUnitName(name);
return (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
```

Comment: Thank you, useful information!!! But do you know how to get javaProject and name??? I'm trying to find some information but no way :-(

Comment: perhaps `JavaModelManager.getJavaModelManager().getJavaModel().getJavaProject()` should return active project. look for examples for ASTParser usage at grepcode: http://grepcode.com/search/usages?id=repo1.maven.org$maven2@org.eclipse.tycho$org.eclipse.jdt.core@3.8.2.v20120814-155456@org$eclipse$jdt$core$dom@ASTParser&type=type&k=u